# PHP variable has different value in while loop

Tags: php

I am using the following function to display my gallery images:

```
<?php
//function call
return showImages();

//function definition
function showImages(){
  $out = "<h1>Image Gallery</h1>";
  $out .= "<ul id='images'>";
  $folder = "img";
  $filesInFolder = new DirectoryIterator($folder);
  $imgnumber = 1;
  while ($filesInFolder->valid()){
    $file = $filesInFolder->current();
    $filename = $file->getFilename();
    $src = "$folder/$filename";
    $fileInfo = new Finfo( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
    $mimeType = $fileInfo->file($src);
    if ($mimeType === 'image/jpeg'){
      $out.= "<li><img id='imgnumber$imgnumber' src='$src' /></li>";
    }
    $filesInFolder->next();
    $imgnumber = $imgnumber + 1;
  }

  $out .= "</ul>";
  return $out;
}
```

The expected result is that **img id** is incremented by 1 each time the while iteration runs. My problem is that the first image has an id of **imgnumber4**. This is my result:

```
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>
<ul id='images'>
  <li><img id='imgnumber4' src='img/1.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber5' src='img/10.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber6' src='img/11.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber7' src='img/12.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber8' src='img/13.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber9' src='img/18.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber10' src='img/2.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber11' src='img/27.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber12' src='img/3.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber13' src='img/4.jpg' /></li>
  <li><img id='imgnumber14' src='img/5.jpg' /></li>
</ul>
```

Can you tell me why it is starting from number 4 and not 1? I have set the variable $imgnumber to be 1 from start so I have no idea why it jumps to 4...

Comment: Echo something outside your `if` block there. Should be obvious.

Comment: maybe the first three images don't meet the conditions are therefore are not listed, but it's still counting up?

Comment: Ahhh I thought that but all the images from that directory are being displayed. Sorry only starting with PHP and couldn't figure that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its your 'if' statement - likely that there are files that are not 'image/jpeg'.
Simply place the line

```
$imgnumber = $imgnumber + 1;
```

within the if statement

Comment: That worked... I thought that but all the images are being displayed that are located in this folder... Sorry to bother you, only practising :/

Comment: Hymm, I only curious now why it jumps to 4 if all the images are meeting the condition of image/jpeg... Thank you once more!

Comment: I cannot answer really without seeing all the files in the directory. Are there system files there ?

Comment: Only those images from what I can see but only got a new Mac and getting used to it, just like to programming. Coming hard so far and sometimes making myself look like a fool but I will get there! Anyway, it's working as expected now. You saved me hours of frustration haha Thank you once more!

Comment: Maybe `.` and `..` and other subdirectories?

Comment: Just saw it is Mac, also `.DS_Store`.